# Vertical progress Bar using rgraph

Tags: rgraph

I am using [Vertical progress bar](http://www.rgraph.net/docs/vprogress.html) from rgraph charts.

My output is
[image]

What i am trying to do is adjust scale in multiple of 10 wrt numticks.
So if my numticks are 6, scale should to 0,10,20,30...60

How can i do this? Is there any other alternative?

Code

```
var vprogress = new RGraph.VProgress({
    id: 'cvs',
    min: 0,
    max: 60,
    value: 46,
    options: {
        colors: ['#5bc0de'],
        tickmarksInner: true,
        gutterRight:35,
        numticks:6,
        tickmarksColor:['black'],
        arrows:true,
        textSize: 12,
        margin: 5,
    }
}).grow();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use the labelsCount option.